# Dynamically insert a script tag without calling function

Tags: javascript, parsing, dynamic

I'm trying to dynamically insert the following:

```
var downloadJsOnLoad = function () {

    var shareThisOne = document.createElement('script');
    shareThisOne.text = 'var switchTo5x=true;';
    document.body.appendChild(shareThisOne);

    var shareThisTwo = document.createElement('script');
    shareThisTwo.src = 'http://w.sharethis.com/button/buttons.js';
    document.body.appendChild(shareThisTwo);

    var text = 'stLight.options({publisher: "a8cae9ce-ebee-4346-9891-a1bfb0aa7005"});';

    var shareThisThree = document.createElement('script');
    shareThisThree.innerHTML = text;
    document.body.appendChild(shareThisThree);

}

jQuery(window).load(function () {
    downloadJsOnLoad();
});
```

Everything works, but I get an error when this javascript is parsed that says stLight is undefined. I'm assuming that it is looking at the stLight.options method as an executable rather than a plain string. How can I get around this to avoid the error?

Comment: This error means `stLight` is not there at all. Are you loading the file that contains the definition of it correctly?

Comment: Do you want it be inserted as string?

Comment: I'm loading the file that contains stLight right before I add this.

Comment: You should add this line only after that file get loaded

Comment: Why would you want to run some JavaScript to insert a script tag that immediately runs more JavaScript? [_Yo dawg..._](http://cdn.memegenerator.net/instances/400x/28015460.jpg)

Comment: When loading the file, do you use `onload`? See: http://jsfiddle.net/3BMrL/.

Comment: I'm trying to defer the parsing of ShareThis javascript. This is how they want it implemented. I'm just trying to add it dynamically after the page loads.

Comment: I've updated with the full code block.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `onload` to make sure the ShareThis code (i.e. the `stLight` variable) exists when using it:

```
shareThisTwo.onload = function() {
    var text = 'stLight.options({publisher: "a8cae9ce-ebee-4346-9891-a1bfb0aa7005"});';

    var shareThisThree = document.createElement('script');
    shareThisThree.innerHTML = text;
    document.body.appendChild(shareThisThree);
};
```

That said, why not just discard the last element creation? You just want to execute code.

```
shareThisTwo.onload = function() {
    stLight.options({publisher: "a8cae9ce-ebee-4346-9891-a1bfb0aa7005"});
};
```

Comment: This was a great suggestion. I set the first tag to a global variable because that's what it was anyway, then added the second script tag dynamically, then just executed the final statement. Worked great!! Thank you for your suggestion.